# Debug Assertion Failed! (Not Normal)

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, assertion

Okay so my problem is an assertion failure. What I don't understand is that my program correctly inputs from the file, to the array, then prints to the screen, but still shows this error and I just can't figure it out.  There's going to be more to this program so please disregard the unused functions.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 272

FILE* csis;

void processFile(char line[]);
int cipher();

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX];

    processFile(line, MAX);

    fclose(csis);
    return (0);
}
void processFile(char line[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    int i = 0;

    if (!(fp = fopen("congress.txt", "r"))) {
        printf("File could not be opened for input.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &line[i]);
        printf("%c", line[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
int cipher() {}
```

Comment: shows us an error message

Comment: What line triggers the assertion failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are closing an unopened file handle, in the future you can initialize your file handles to NULL and then test before closing.

```
FILE *csis = NULL;
...
if (csis)
    fclose(csis);
```

Comment: Alan I can't upvote you I'm sorry, but this was my problem. So thank you very much for fixing my stupidity! :D

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", &line[i]);
```